# Cheeger-Gromov convergence of manifolds implies Gromov-Hausdorff convergence

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, gromov-hausdorff-limit

I'm reading about convergence of Riemannian manifolds:

A sequence of pointed complete Riemannian manifolds is said to converge in the pointed $C^{m, \alpha}$ topology $(M_i, p_i, g_i) \rightarrow (M,p,g)$ if for every $R > 0$ we can find
a domain $\Omega \supset B (p,R) \subset M$ and embeddings $F_i : \Omega → M_i$ for large i such that
$F_i (\Omega) \supset B(p_i ,R)$ and $F_i^* g_i \rightarrow g$ on $\Omega$ in the $C^{m, \alpha}$ topology.

Then it is stated that it is easy to see that
this type of convergence implies pointed Gromov-Hausdorff convergence.

I haven't been able to figure out how to see this. Can you help me with this? I guess we need to contruct some metric on $M \sqcup M_i$ using the $C^{m, \alpha}$-convergence of $F^*g_i$ to see this?

Comment: Can you recall the definition of the pointed Gromov-Hausdorff convergence?

Comment: We say that $(X_i ,x_i , d_i ) → (X,x,d)$ in the pointed Gromov-Hausdorff topology if for all $R$, the closed metric balls
$(\overline{B}(x_i ,R), x_i ,d_i) \rightarrow (\overline{B}(x,R),x,d)$ converge with respect to the pointed Gromov-Hausdorff metric ($d_{G-H}((X,x), (Y,y)) = \inf\{d_H(X, Y) + d(x, y)\}$)

Comment: It suffices to show that on a compact domain, if two Riemannian metrics are sufficiently $C^0$ close, then their respective distance functions are $C^0$ close.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me some further pointers? What does it mean for the distance functions to be close? That $d_M(x, y)$ and $d_{M_i}(F_i(x), F_i(y))$ are close? And with this information I then define some metric on the disjoint union of these two compact spaces?

Comment: Distance is a continuous function on $M\time M$. Two distance functions are close if they are close with respect to the $C^0$ norm.